# SQL Multilevel Table Implementation

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am looking for methods to implement these three tables

1st level table:
Employee table - Contains dep_id (department id) and job_code (designation)

2nd level table:
Department table - Contains dep_id (department id) and dep_name (department name)

3rd level tables:
Individual department tables - Contains job_code(designation) and no(No of employees at that designation)

I want the details from the 3rd level table depending on the queried job_code. This is how. I will go to level 2 with dep_id and job_code. In level 2 I will find the name of the TABLE with dep_id. I will then go to that particular table to find the desired information.

Please suggest how to implement this in Oracle SQL or any other architecture to implement this. For ex: I can keep dep_id in 3rd level tables, but that way all the rows in 3rd level individual dept tables will have same values. I can merge level 2 and level 3 tables, but that would mean one column extra, having same values in a bunch of rows.
I am a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have one table per department.

In fact, the data you propose storing in that table (number of employees per job_code per department) can be retrieved from the employee table.

Comment: Yeah! Actually, I wanted to extract some other information, through this pathway. Can you suggest something other than having one table per department